# Unable to copy files using xcopy sqlcmd

Tags: sqlcmd

I am copying files from one server to another through `sqlcmd`. I am able to get the output of the select statement, but am unable to copy. I am unable to find the syntax for copying files through `sqlcmd xcopy`.

```
H:\>sqlcmd -S cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst -Q "xcopy d:\sysdba\ e:\"
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server CX-SISCSQLTEST\SQLINST, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
```

I am able to get output of following:

```
H:\>sqlcmd -S cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst -Q "select * from sysaltfiles"
```

What is the `xcopy sqlcmd` syntax for copying files?

Comment: iam using this H:\>sqlcmd -S cx-siscsqltest\sqlinst -Q "xp_cmdshell 'xcopy \\av-riscvmdbut10\db
ms\MS SQL\MSSQL2008 R2\SQL 2008 R2 SP3\SQLServer2008R2SP3-KB2979597-x64-ENU.exe
   d:\sysdba1 /s /e /i /y'"

Comment: its giving me invalid no of parameters